# Use linq to match up pairs of rows in a set

Tags: c#, linq

In the system I use modifications to data are received in pairs of rows old and new with a RowMod flag, for example deleted, added, updated and unchanged rows come through as:

```
RowID Data    RowMod
Row1  "fish"  "" 
Row1  "fish"  "D" 
Row2  "cat"   "A"
Row3  "fox"   ""
Row3  "dog"   "U"
Row4  "mouse" ""
```

I'd like to match these up using the RowID that each row has and get something like:

```
RowID OldData NewData RowMod
Row1  "fish"  null    "D"
Row2  null    "cat"   "A"
Row3  "fox"   "dog"   "U"
Row4  "mouse" "mouse" ""
```

Comment: Shouldn't the NewData for a delete be null and for unchanged be the same as OldData?

Comment: @juharr thinking about it yes, it'd probably make the resulting dataset more useful, I'll edit...

Comment: What is supposed to happen if there are more than two updates? Like Row1,"first",A -> Row1,"second",U -> Row1,"second",D

Comment: I'm trying to understand your logic on how to combine rows. It seems like if `RowMod == ""` then `Data` is `OldData`, but `"fish"` and `"mouse"` don't seem to follow the rule. Can you please be more explicit in your logic than "get something like"?

Comment: What is the difference between Row2 and Row4? Both of them has one record, but old data of the former is null whereas the same for the latter is "mouse"

Comment: @serdar, row 2 is an Add ("A"), row 4 is Unchanged ("")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = new[]
        {
            new DataRow(1,"fish",""),
            new DataRow(1,"fish","D"),
            new DataRow(2,"cat","A"),
            new DataRow(3,"fox",""),
            new DataRow(3,"dog","U"),
            new DataRow(4,"mouse","")
        };

        var result = rows
            .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(g => new 
            {
                Count = g.Count(),
                Id = g.First().Id,
                FirstRow = g.First(),
                LastRow = g.Last() 
            }).Select(item => new 
            {
                RowId = item.Id,
                OldData = item.Count == 1 && item.FirstRow.RowMod != "" ? null : item.FirstRow.Data,
                NewData = item.LastRow.RowMod == "D" ? null : item.LastRow.Data,
                RowMod = item.LastRow.RowMod 
            });

            //Or using query syntax
            var result2 = from x in rows
                          orderby x.Id, x.RowMod
                          group x by x.Id into g
                          select new
                          {
                              RowId = g.First().Id,
                              OldData = g.Count() == 1 && g.First().RowMod != "" ? null : g.First().Data,
                              NewData = g.Last().RowMod == "D" ? null : g.Last().Data,
                              RowMod = g.Last().RowMod
                          };

        // Test
        Console.WriteLine("RowID\tOldData\tNewData\tRowMod");
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t'{1}'\t'{2}'\t'{3}'",item.RowId,item.OldData ?? "null",item.NewData ?? "null",item.RowMod);
        }
    }
}

public class DataRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string RowMod { get; set; }

    public DataRow(int id, string data, string rowMod)
    {
        Id = id;
        Data = data;
        RowMod = rowMod;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
RowID   OldData NewData RowMod
1       'fish'  'null'  'D'
2       'null'  'cat'   'A'
3       'fox'   'dog'   'U'
4       'mouse'  'mouse' ''
```

Comment: Updated to fix the issue with Delete entries

Comment: @webturner you can do it in one swing too but it's easier to read this way

Comment: Thanks, Florian. I've added the query syntax version with OrderBy in case of unsorted input data. (I did it in one select too)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best way to achieve your requirement but this is what I have:-

```
var result = rows.GroupBy(x => x.RowId)
                 .Select(x => 
          {
             var firstData = x.FirstOrDefault();
             var secondData = x.Count() == 1 ? x.First().RowMod == "A" ? firstData : null
                                             : x.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
          return new
          {
              RowId = x.Key,
              OldData = firstData.RowMod == "A" ? null : firstData.Data,
              NewData = secondData != null ? secondData.Data : null,
              RowMod = String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstData.RowMod) && secondData != null ?
                                      secondData.RowMod : firstData.RowMod
          };
      });
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BrP3Qg).

Answer (score 0):

Getting the two parts of the intended object can be done iteratively:

```
foreach(var rowId in myList.Select(x => x.RowId).Distinct())
{
    //get the left item
    var leftItem = myList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowId == rowId && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.rowmod);

    //get the right item
    var rightItem = myList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowId == rowId && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.rowmod);
}
```

Your question doesn't specify how you create the second object. Is it a different class?
Either way, you can extrapolate from the above snippet that either item might be `null` if it doesn't exist in the original set.

All you need to do is use those found objects to create your new object.

Comment: This would iterate the collection n times, so your complexity is in O(n^2) where it could be in O(n).

Comment: I can't make a fully optimized snippet if part of the solution isn't mentioned in the question (how the resulting object is constructed). Given the lack of actual code in the question, answering with a difficult yet highly optimized answer only leads to blind copy/pasting instead of understanding the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are more elegant ways to do it, but this produces the output you expect:

```
public class MyClass
            {
                public int RowID { get; set; }
                public string Data { get; set; }
                public string RowMod { get; set; }
            }

  var result = (from id in myList.Select(x => x.RowID).Distinct()
            let oldData = myList.Where(x => x.RowID == id).SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowMod.Equals("")) != null
                ? myList.Where(x => x.RowID == id).Single(x => x.RowMod.Equals("")).Data
                : null
            let newData = myList.Where(x => x.RowID == id).SingleOrDefault(x => !x.RowMod.Equals("")) != null
                ? myList.Where(x => x.RowID == id).Single(x => !x.RowMod.Equals("")).Data
                : null
            let rowMod = myList.Where(x => x.RowID == id).SingleOrDefault(x => !x.RowMod.Equals("")) != null
                ? myList.Where(x => x.RowID == id).Single(x => !x.RowMod.Equals("")).RowMod
                : null
            select new
                   {
                       RowID = id,
                       OldData = oldData,
                       NewData = rowMod == null ? oldData : rowMod.Equals("D") ? null : newData,
                       RowMod = rowMod
                   });
foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", item.RowID, item.OldData ?? "null", item.NewData ?? "null", item.RowMod ?? "-");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I love LINQ a lot, I don't think it is appropriate here as you want to buffer some values while iterating. If you do this with LINQ, it will be at best not performing well, at worst it will iterate the collection multiple times. It also looks way cleaner this way in my opinion.

```
IEnumerable<TargetClass> MapOldValues(IEnumerable<SourceClass> source)
{
    var buffer = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        string oldValue;
        buffer.TryGetValue(item.RowId, out oldValue); 
        yield return new TargetClass
                          {
                              RowId = item.RowId, 
                              OldData = oldValue, 
                              NewData = (item.RowMod == "D" ? null : item.Data), 
                              RowMod = item.RowMod  };
        // if the rows come sorted by ID, you can clear old values from
        // the buffer to save memory at this point:
        // if(oldValue == null) { buffer.Clear(); }
        buffer[item.RowId] = item.Data;
    }
}
```

if you then only want the latest updates, you can go with LINQ:

```
var latestChanges = MapOldValues(source).GroupBy(x => x.RowId).Select(x => x.Last());
```